# Regex: extract CSS styles from CSS file

Tags: ruby, regex, perl

I have a big CSS file with all CSS we need for our internal framework, but I only need a few of the styles. So I want to extract the style I want. I used regular expression to extract them:

```
cssFileContent.scan(/\.#{cssName}.*?\{.+?\}/im)
```

In Ruby, `scan` means extract the patter from string, `cssName is` the CSS style name
i - case insensitive
m - dot match everything so that \n will be matched too

It gives me some style blocks, but skip one every time. For example, I have `.abc-style { }` and `.def-style { }`, but result is like:

```
.abc-style {

}

}
```

so def-style is skipped.

Can someone give me any point why? And how to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try excluding the closing bracket and make the collection greedy like this:

```
cssFileContent.scan(/\.#{cssName}.*?\{[^\}]+\}/im)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a regex I would use a CSS parser to do this.

There are plenty on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/) to chose from, for e.g. [`CSS`](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS), [`CSS::SAC`](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aSAC), [`CSS::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aTiny) & [`CSS::Croco`](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aCroco). Choose the one which best fits your needs.

Here is an example using [`CSS::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aTiny)...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CSS::Tiny;

my $css = CSS::Tiny->read('your_stylesheet.css');
my $new = CSS::Tiny->new;

# styles I want to extract
$new->{$_} = $css->{$_} for qw/.abc-style .def-style/;

$new->write('extracted_styles.css');
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative :)